# Implementing JQuery into HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am experienced with Javascript, HTML and CSS, but I have avoided jQuery simply because I am not familiar with it.

Finally, I am forced to face it. I wanted some script that would make a function similar to Cookie Clickers "+1" effect when you click the cookie ( http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/ ) and I was given the perfect solution by @shipshape. However, I have absolutely no clue where to implement the jQuery and how to link it.

Really sorry for the stupid question, no googled answered seem to really help me.

Thank you guys!

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var $newPlus = $('<div class="plus">+1</div>');
  $('#area').append($newPlus);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $newPlus.addClass('fade');
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $newPlus.remove();
  }, 650);
});
```

```css
#area {
  position: relative;
  padding: 70px;
}
#area .plus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: top 300ms ease-out, opacity 600ms ease-in-out;
}
#area .plus.fade {
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area">
  <button>Plus One</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just google "html include javascript file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your JS code in `$(document).ready(function() { //your code });` and you can reference in it a `script` tag in the footer, body, or header! Or you can reference a file like: `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`.

You need to put it after you reference the jQuery file though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var $newPlus = $('<div class="plus">+1</div>');
    $('#area').append($newPlus);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $newPlus.addClass('fade');
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $newPlus.remove();
    }, 650);
  });
});
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks chris!

Answer (score 0):

You typically put the jQuery script tag in the `<head>` of your page (like other scripts and stylesheet `link` tags), but it can go anywhere on the page. Then your jQuery code typically goes somewhere in the body (can go at the end of the document, before `</body>`) inside of script tags wrapped in `$(document).ready()`.

The script/document ready looks like this. Here is a reference - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    // your jQuery code goes here
  });
</script>
```